How do I construct a `numpy.typing.DtypeLike` for a `numpy` structured array?
Suppose I have a numpy structured array with the dtype:
import numpy as np

EXAMPLE_DTYPE = np.dtype([("alpha", np.str_), ("beta", np.int64)])

I can then do:
print(npt.NDArray[EXAMPLE_DTYPE])
>> numpy.ndarray[typing.Any, numpy.dtype[dtype([('alpha', '<U'), ('beta', '<i8')])]]

But I can't use that output as the type hint itself ("call expressions are not allowed in type hints").
I have to instead construct a DtypeLike:
numpy.typing.DTypeLike = typing.Union[...]

Based on what I could understand of the docs I linked for DTypeLike, I wrote down the following:
data: np.ndarray[np.typing.Any, tuple[tuple["hello", "<U"], tuple["world", "<i8"]]] = np.array([("hello", 0), ("world", 1)], dtype=EXAMPLE_DTYPE)

This does not work however, because PyLance (for example) complains about that "hello" and "world" are not defined. Not sure if the situation is different with something like MyPy, as I do not have the time to test it out right now.
How can I construct this DTypeLike correctly for static type checkers to consume? Is there a way to convert a dtype into a DTypeLike?

dtypes are already dtypelike. That's not the problem. I'm not sure NumPy's type hint support is actually mature enough to handle this use case yet.
